# What is generally understood by the expression "like peas in a pod" when said of people?

Tags: phrase-meaning, simile

I have always understood "like peas in a pod", when said of people, to mean that they are *very similar in appearance* (or possibly in character), like

> Alia and her sister are like peas in a pod! Are they twins? If they had on the same outfit I wouldn't know one from the other.

But in recent years I have noticed that my mum (who I presumably at least partly learned the phrase from), has often been using "like peas in a pod" to mean something like *inseparable* (similar to "joined at the hip", assuming I know the meaning of *that* phrase), like

> Bukky and Cleo are like peas in a pod these days; I can't remember the last time I saw one without the other.

Are either or both of us <strike>losing our marbles</strike> using this phrase in an unusual way? Or are we both correct?

Comment: You are correct, and Mom is simply wrong.  Of course .... language, and idiom uses, change over time. But quite simply, the "Mom example" you give is plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - the idiom means that two people *are alike*, just as you would expect all the peas inside a pod to look the same. I should point out that peas in a literal pod are not joined to each other! They are joined to the pod but are easily separated from it, hence another English idiom that if something is easy it is "like shelling peas"!

There are probably loads of idioms to mean "inseparable", but the one that leaps to mind is "joined at the hip".

Comment: Thanks! It is always pleasant to be told "you are correct" haha. Your point about peas not being joined is a good one, but what gave me doubts (although every simile has to break down somewhere and reasoning about their accuracy is perhaps not always productive) was that, while peas are alike whether they are in the pod or not, they are only inseparable while in the pod! Also, I don't think I have heard the phrase "like shelling peas" to mean "easy" before - thanks for the bonus tip :)

Comment: Hmm.  peas are not in any way inseparable. it's perfectly simple to take one out and leave one.  they're no more inseparable than oranges hanging on a tree. you just pick one.  (it's hard to think of "inseparable" examples, other than the (slightly disturbing) co-joined twins example. what about "the north and south pole of a magnet".)

Comment: there are various "go together" idioms (horse & carriage, etc); I can't think of any other inseparable idioms as such than joined at the hip

Comment: @Fattie how do you separate two peas in a pod, without taking at least one of them out of the pod?

Comment: hi @Zanna - hmm. It's difficult to understand your point?  Are you saying *"Fattie, even though you are a native English speaker, you may be mistaken"*.  Or are you saying *"Even though I now understand how the phrase is used in English, I am going to use it another way"*  Or are you saying *"From now on English speakers should use the phrase in a different way, due to the information I am presenting here?"*  Or what?  The idiom means "are alike".  **End of story.**  It has no connection, at all, to greenness, to seprability, to shelling, to veghetarianism, or anything else.

Comment: "although every simile has to break down somewhere and reasoning about their accuracy is perhaps not always productive"  Do note that this sentence is not real,ly correct.  (1) it's not a simile, it's idiomatic.  (2) idioms don't "break down" logically because they don't "start" logically and have, utterly, no relationship in any way to logic. they're idioms.  (3) you can't "reason" about the "accuracy" of idioms; no concept of "accuracy" or "reasoning" is related to idioms. they're idiomatic.